# Can't stub SimpleMessageListenerContainer isActive method [Spring AMQP Rabbit]

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to create unit tests for my Spring EventListeners that toggle SimpleMessageListenerContainer (start/stop).

The code I'm trying to test:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringEventsListeners {
    private static CPLocation cpLocation = CPLoggingFactory.createCPLocation(SpringEventsListeners.class);

    private ConfigurationServiceImpl configService;

    //Constructor Injection for Testability.
    public SpringEventsListeners(final ConfigurationServiceImpl configService) {
        this.configService = configService;
    }

    /**
     * Rabbit listeners might be started/stopped after a refresh depending on a property.
     * In case a change is needed, we perform it.
     */
    @EventListener(classes= { ApplicationReadyEvent.class, EnvironmentChangeEvent.class })
    public void handleRabbitListenerToggle() {
        String method = "handleRabbitListenerToggle";
        cpLocation.info(method, "Received refresh event. Determining action.");
        
        boolean shouldActivateRabbit = configService.shouldActivateRabbitListeners();
        for (SimpleMessageListenerContainer container : configService.getAllRabbitSimpleMessageListenerContainers()) {
            if (shouldActivateRabbit && !container.isActive()) {
                container.start();
                cpLocation.info(method, "Starting container: "+Arrays.toString(container.getQueueNames()));
            }
            else if (!shouldActivateRabbit && container.isActive()) {
                container.shutdown();
                cpLocation.info(method, "Shutting down container: "+Arrays.toString(container.getQueueNames()));
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Minimal test (tests nothing):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SpringEventsListenersTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private SpringEventsListeners classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private ConfigurationServiceImpl mockConfigurationService;

    @Mock
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer mockSimpleMessageListenerContainer;

    @Test
    public void testToggleTrue() {
        //Given
        given(mockConfigurationService.shouldActivateRabbitListeners()).willReturn(true);
        given(mockConfigurationService.getAllRabbitSimpleMessageListenerContainers()).willReturn(Arrays.asList(mockSimpleMessageListenerContainer));
        given(mockSimpleMessageListenerContainer.isActive()).willReturn(false);
        //When
        classUnderTest.handleRabbitListenerToggle();
        Assert.assertThat(true, is(true));
    }
}
```

The tests won't run as I receive a NullPointerException on `given(mockSimpleMessageListenerContainer.isActive()).willReturn(false);`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.isActive(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1271)
> at
> com.cp.order.listener.SpringEventsListenersTests.testToggleTrue(SpringEventsListenersTests.java:36)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
> at
> org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

I will also need to assert that .shutdown or .start were called on the container, so it needs to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can't mock `final` methods (`isActive()` is final).

You could use reflection (e.g. `DirectFieldAccessor`) to check the `active` field instead.

That said, mocking the listener container is rather unusual; it is a complex piece of code; perhaps you could explain exactly what you are trying to test?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get 80% test coverage and noticed that this class is not covered at all. So I thought I could unit test these 2 simple if-elseifs, and make sure that the container is being toggled correctly according to the parameters.

Comment: You should use the interface `MessageListenerContainer` instead, and mock that and verify `start()` and `stop()` are called (stop calls shutdown).